# android - take a picture with the camera and share it with all

Tags: android, server, share, photo

I would like to develop an app on Android that allows me to take a picture with the camera and share it instantly with all the people that have my app.
it is clearly a client / server application.

until now I did this.
1) I took a web space on altervista with db
2) I developed the client side so that a photo taken with the application to be put on the server (in db)

I'll have to do this:
1) each time a picture is stored in the database part of a notification to all those have the app.
2) when other users launch the app's automatic download of the pictures that have not yet displayed.

the mechanism is somewhat reminiscent to facebook.
but I have many doubts about what I'm doing.

there is a better way to develop this type of app?
Also if you have suggestions about the kind of architecture to use.
By the time I got a web space on altervista but after that I think I'll take a dedicated client or a cloud.
mmm.. I feel that is not the best way to develop my app.

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: There are a few services that can help you out, e.g. parse.com . Holds pictures, data, sends push notifications, lets you run cloud functions and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend do it as following.

Create one time value in server and change it to time new picture loaded.

And in your apps repeatedly check that value. If that value is grater than time in app get last image load new image